# AJAX isn't treating json as json

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

My AJAX call isn't treating the data from server as JSON, even if i set the datatype in json:

```
function Getmateriasfromserver(callback){
    var status_aux;
//Requisição HTTP, por dados provindos do url dado. Caso os dados recebidos sejam os esperados, entra no caso do SUCCESS
return $.ajax({
    url: 'materiasphp/materias.php',
dateType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
        status_aux = data;
        callback(status_aux);
    var test = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(test[1]);
    }
```

Console print test[1] = "["

Comment: What console log you are getting for `console.log(data);` you have converted data into String by using `JSON.stringify(data);` try `console.log(data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var test = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Should probably be

```
var test = JSON.parse(data);
// or just 
var test = data;
```

Because if you stringify it, then you are accessing letters in the string with bracket notation.

```
var test="cat":
console.log(test[0]);
```

Is `c`, the first letter in the **string**

Answer (score 2):

You also have a typo in your code.  `dateType:` should be `dataType:`

```
return $.ajax({
  url: 'materiasphp/materias.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a text based data format.

`JSON.stringify(data);` takes `data` and converts it to a JSON text, which it stores in a string.

`console.log(test[1]);` then reads the character at index 1 in that string and displays it.

This is normal behaviour.

If you want to deal with the data as a JavaScript data structure then **don't convert it to JSON**!.

Just work directly with the data structure in `data`.